# Remove trailing zero in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have Strings (from DB), which may contain numeric values. If it contains numeric values, I'd like to remove trailing zeros such as:

- `10.0000`
- `10.234000`

`str.replaceAll("\\.0*$", "")`, works on the first one, but not the second one.

A lot of the answers point to use `BigDecimal`, but the `String` I get may not be numeric. So I think a better solution probably is through the Regex.

Comment: Just convert the string to an int and convert it back to a string.

Comment: @David: That cuts of all non-integers.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

there are possibilities:

```
1000    -> 1000
10.000  -> 10 (without point in result)
10.0100 -> 10.01 
10.1234 -> 10.1234
```

I am lazy and stupid, just

```
s = s.indexOf(".") < 0 ? s : s.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
```

Same solution using `contains` instead of `indexOf` as mentioned in some of the comments for easy understanding

```
 s = s.contains(".") ? s.replaceAll("0*$","").replaceAll("\\.$","") : s
```

Comment: A single regex suffices, see my answer.

Comment: You can replace `s.indexOf(".") < 0` with `!s.contains(".")` for clarity.

Comment: @Project  `contains()` and `indexOf()` are doing exactly same thing. You can check the implementation of `contains()`

Comment: @Kent "For clarity"

Comment: @Sergey I run the code in my Eye-JRE, and it works for `0.0` and `6.0`

Comment: but in Android does not, too strange((

Answer (score 27):

Use **DecimalFormat**, its cleanest way

```
String s = "10.1200";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.#####");
String result = decimalFormat.format(Double.valueOf(s));
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: And surely also the slowest (and maybe even the most complicated?).

Comment: @maaartinus why is this complicated? As someone who doesn't know regex very well, I can understand this code and adapt it to what I need. Regex may be faster, but syntax-wise, it's just a mess to me.

Comment: @TheWanderer On the second thought, I mostly agree with you. The regex is actually pretty simple (and I'd recommend to learn regexes at this level), but more complicated regexes get too messy too fast.

Answer (score 17):

[Kent's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent) string manipulation answer magically works and also caters for precision loss, But here's a cleaner solution using BigDecimal

```
String value = "10.234000";
BigDecimal stripedVal = new BigDecimal(value).stripTrailingZeros();
```

You can then convert to other types

```
String stringValue = stripedVal.toPlainString();
double doubleValue = stripedVal.doubleValue();
long longValue = stripedVal.longValue();
```

If precision loss is an ultimate concern for you, then obtain the exact primitive value. This would throw ArithmeticException if there'll be any precision loss for the primitive. See below

```
int intValue = stripedVal.intValueExact();
```

Comment: Not exactly what OP asked (does not work for non-numeric values) but exactly what I needed - thank you!

Answer (score 11):

```
String value = "10.010"
String s = new DecimalFormat("0.####").format(Double.parseDouble(value));
System.out.println(s);

Output:

   10.01
```

Comment: Hiya there, while this may well answer the question, please be aware that other users might not be as knowledgeable as you. Why don't you add a little explanation as to why this code works? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I find all the other solution too complicated. Simply

```
s.replaceFirst("\\.0*$|(\\.\\d*?)0+$", "$1");
```

does the job. It tries the first alternative first, so that dot followed by all zeros gets replaced by nothing (as the group doesn't get set). Otherwise, if it finds a dot followed by some digits (as few as possible due to the lazy quantifier `*?`) followed by some zeros, the zeros get discarded as they're not included in the group. [It works](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/RemoveTrailingZerosTest.java).

#### Warning

My code relies on my [assumption that appending a unmatched group does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27439931/581205). This is true for the Oracle implementation, but not for others, including **Android**, which seem to append the string "null". I'd call the such implementations broken as it just may no sense, but they're [correct according to the Javadoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27440141/581205).

Comment: What is $1? It added null to the end of my String

Comment: @RohanKandwal `$1` is `matcher.group(1)`, but what is your test case? I have quite a few test cases as you can see and they all work.

Comment: @Everett Is there any input, too? It may be wrong, but the output is pretty useless for finding the problem.

Comment: @maaartinus: Looking at their profiles, it is possible that they execute the code on Android.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for all the following examples:

```
"1" -> "1"
"1.0" -> "1"
"1.01500" -> "1.015"
"1.103" -> "1.103"

s = s.replaceAll("()\\.0+$|(\\..+?)0+$", "$2");
```

Comment: above solution is not working for me for 890.0 I am getting 890null

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing

```
(\d*\.\d*)0*$
```

by

```
\1
```

?

Comment: Any java built in functions to use?

Comment: this has problem with the 1st example.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace with:

```
String result = (str.indexOf(".")>=0?str.replaceAll("\\.?0+$",""):str);
```

To keep the Regex as simple as possible. (And account for inputs like `1000` as pointed out in comments)

Comment: Right. I just thought of "trailing zeros". Not to the mathematical representation of the number. My bad. 
In this case, Kent's answer (checking for "." before applying Regex) is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation with possibility to select numbers of digits after divider:

```
public static String removeTrailingZero(String number, int minPrecise, char divider) {
    int dividerIndex = number.indexOf(divider);

    if (dividerIndex == -1) {
        return number;
    }

    int removeCount = 0;
    for (int i = dividerIndex + 1; i < number.length(); i++) {
        if (number.charAt(i) == '0') {
            removeCount++;
        } else {
            removeCount = 0;
        }
    }

    int fracLen = number.length() - dividerIndex - 1;

    if (fracLen - removeCount < minPrecise) {
        removeCount = fracLen - minPrecise;
    }

    if (removeCount < 0) {
        return number;
    }

    String result = number.substring(0, number.length() - removeCount);

    if (result.endsWith(String.valueOf(divider))) {
        return result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **Kent**'s answer.

Be careful with regex in **Kotlin**. You have to manually write `Regex()` constructor instead of a simple string!

```
s = if (s.contains(".")) 
        s.replace(Regex("0*\$"),"").replace(Regex("\\.\$"),"") 
    else s
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.#####");

String value1 = df.format(101.00000);
String value2 = df.format(102.02000);
String value3 = df.format(103.20000);
String value4 = df.format(104.30020);
```

Output:

```
101
102.02
103.2
104.3002
```

Answer (score -1):

Separate out the fraction part first. Then you can use the below logic.

```
BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(345000);
BigDecimal div = new BigDecimal(10).pow(Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(value.intValue()));
System.out.println(value.divide(div).intValue());
```