# confusion in behavior of capturing groups in java regex

Tags: java, regex, replace

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24213093/581205) I recommended using

```
s.replaceFirst("\\.0*$|(\\.\\d*?)0+$", "$1");
```

but two people complained that the result contained the string "null", e.g., `23.null`. This could be explained by `$1` (i.e., `group(1)`) being `null`, which could be transformed via `String.valueOf` to the string "null". However, I always get the empty string. My [testcase](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/RemoveTrailingZerosTest.java) covers it and

```
assertEquals("23", removeTrailingZeros("23.00"));
```

passes. Is the exact behavior undefined?

Comment: I don't think `$1` will come back as `null`. It can be just an empty string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Why not? Do you think `replaceAll` would be better?

Comment: @anubhava But there are people claiming it, see my first link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class from the reference implementation doesn't specify the behavior of `appendReplacement` method when a capturing group which doesn't capture anything (`null`) is specified in the replacement string. While the behavior of `group` method is clear, nothing is mentioned in `appendReplacement` method.

Below are 3 exhibits of difference in implementation for the case above:

- The reference implementation does not append anything (or we can say append an empty string) for the case above.
- GNU Classpath and Android's implementation appends `null` for the case above.

Some code has been omitted for the sake of brevity, and is indicated by `...`.

### 1) Sun/Oracle JDK, OpenJDK  (Reference implementation)

For the reference implementation (Sun/Oracle JDK and OpenJDK), the code for `appendReplacement` doesn't seem to have changed from Java 6, and it will not append anything when a capturing group doesn't capture anything:

```
        } else if (nextChar == '$') {
            // Skip past $
            cursor++;
            // The first number is always a group
            int refNum = (int)replacement.charAt(cursor) - '0';
            if ((refNum < 0)||(refNum > 9))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Illegal group reference");
            cursor++;

            // Capture the largest legal group string
            ...

            // Append group
            if (start(refNum) != -1 && end(refNum) != -1)
                result.append(text, start(refNum), end(refNum));
        } else {
```

#### Reference

- [jdk6/98e143b44620](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/98e143b44620/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#l747)
- [jdk8/687fd7c7986d](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#l879)

### 2) GNU Classpath

GNU Classpath, which is a complete reimplementation of Java Class Library has a different implementation for `appendReplacement` in the case above. In Classpath, the classes in `java.util.regex` package in Classpath is just a wrapper for classes in `gnu.java.util.regex`.

[`Matcher.appendReplacement`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/classpath.git/tree/java/util/regex/Matcher.java?id=2016893a79012414f0dd2475230e17bf0b846aed#n136) calls `RE.getReplacement` to process replacement for the matched portion:

```
  public Matcher appendReplacement (StringBuffer sb, String replacement)
    throws IllegalStateException
  {
    assertMatchOp();
    sb.append(input.subSequence(appendPosition,
                                match.getStartIndex()).toString());
    sb.append(RE.getReplacement(replacement, match,
        RE.REG_REPLACE_USE_BACKSLASHESCAPE));
    appendPosition = match.getEndIndex();
    return this;
  }
```

[`RE.getReplacement`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/classpath.git/tree/gnu/java/util/regex/RE.java?id=2016893a79012414f0dd2475230e17bf0b846aed#n2443) calls `REMatch.substituteInto` to get the content of the capturing group and appends its result directly:

```
                  case '$':
                    int i1 = i + 1;
                    while (i1 < replace.length () &&
                           Character.isDigit (replace.charAt (i1)))
                      i1++;
                    sb.append (m.substituteInto (replace.substring (i, i1)));
                    i = i1 - 1;
                    break;
```

[`REMatch.substituteInto`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/classpath.git/tree/gnu/java/util/regex/REMatch.java#n310) appends the result of `REMatch.toString(int)` directly without checking whether the capturing group has captured anything:

```
        if ((input.charAt (pos) == '$')
            && (Character.isDigit (input.charAt (pos + 1))))
          {
            // Omitted code parses the group number into val
            ...

            if (val < start.length)
              {
                output.append (toString (val));
              }
          }
```

And [`REMatch.toString(int)`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/classpath.git/tree/gnu/java/util/regex/REMatch.java#n212) returns `null` when the capturing group doesn't capture (irrelevant code has been omitted).

```
  public String toString (int sub)
  {
    if ((sub >= start.length) || sub < 0)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException ("No group " + sub);
    if (start[sub] == -1)
      return null;
    ...
  }
```

So in GNU Classpath's case, `null` will be appended to the string when a capturing group which fails to capture anything is specified in the replacement string.

### 3) Android Open Source Project - Java Core Libraries

In Android, [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/5b87698ae6d115bfa40f6953b2f5daf20124e14b/luni/src/main/java/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#109) calls private method `appendEvaluated`, which in turn directly appends the result of `group(int)` to the replacement string.

```
public Matcher appendReplacement(StringBuffer buffer, String replacement) {
    buffer.append(input.substring(appendPos, start()));
    appendEvaluated(buffer, replacement);
    appendPos = end();
    return this;
}

private void appendEvaluated(StringBuffer buffer, String s) {
    boolean escape = false;
    boolean dollar = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c == '\\' && !escape) {
            escape = true;
        } else if (c == '$' && !escape) {
            dollar = true;
        } else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9' && dollar) {
            buffer.append(group(c - '0'));
            dollar = false;
        } else {
            buffer.append(c);
            dollar = false;
            escape = false;
        }
    }
    // This seemingly stupid piece of code reproduces a JDK bug.
    if (escape) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(s.length());
    }
}
```

Since `Matcher.group(int)` returns `null` for capturing group which fails to capture, `Matcher.appendReplacement` appends `null` when the capturing group is referred to in the replacement string.

It is most likely that the 2 people complaining to you are running their code on Android.

Answer (score 4):

Having had a careful look at the Javadoc, I conclude that:

1. `$1` is equivalent to calling `group(1)`, which is [specified to return `null`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)) when the group didn't get captured.
2. The handling of `nulls` in the replacement expression is unspecified.

The wording of the [relevant parts of the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) is on the whole surprisingly vague (emphasis mine):

> Dollar signs ***may*** be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above...

Answer (score 2):

You have two alternatives `|` or-ed together, but only the second is between `( )` hence if the first alternative is matched, group 1 is null.

In general place the parentheses around all alternatives

In your case you want to replace

- "xxx.00000" by "xxx" or else
- "xxx.yyy00" by "xxx.yyy"

Better do that in two steps, as that is more readable:

- "xxx.y*00" by "xxx.y*" then
- "xxx." by "xxx"

This does a bit extra, changing an initial "1." to "1".
So:

```
.replaceFirst("(\\.\\d*?)0+$", "$1").replaceFirst("\\.$", "");
```