# Difference between ? or | in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression),

- **?**  => Matches the preceding element zero or one time. For example, ab?c matches only "ac" or "abc".
- **|**  => The choice (also known as alternation or set union) operator matches either the expression before or the expression after the operator. For example, abc|def matches "abc" or "def".

Here is the code tried;

```
String yuStr =  "-7.00, 10.00, 0.00, -212.000";

//Using ?
System.out.println(yuStr.replaceAll("-?(\\d+)\\.\\d+", "$1"));

//Using |
System.out.println(yuStr.replaceAll("-|(\\d+)\\.\\d+", "$1"));
```

However, both of two ways will give the same output

```
7, 10, 0, 212
```

Is my assumption right, according to Wiki doc above, in second way with **?**, it is choice between expression before operator `-` and expression after operator `(\\d+)` ?

My question is, why the second way (with **|**) is working the same way like first one (with **?**) ?

Comment: They are not the same, they happen to produce the same output in this example. Change the replacement string to `"<$1>"` and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same, they just happen to produce the same output for your example.

The 4 matches in the first regex:

```
-7.00, 10.00, 0.00, -212.000
-1---  |   |  |  |  |      |
       11---  |  |  |      |
              1---  |      |
                    -111----
```

In each match, the capturing group captures the whole part of the decimal number, and all four matches are replaced by the content of the capturing group.

The 6 matches in the second regex:

```
-7.00, 10.00, 0.00, -212.000
-|  |  |   |  |  |  ||     |
 1---  |   |  |  |  ||     |
       11---  |  |  ||     |
              1---  ||     |
                    -|     |
                     111----
```

The capturing group only captures some text in 4 matches. In the other 2 matches, the capturing group doesn't capture anything.

In Oracle/OpenJDK, referring to a group that captures nothing in the replacement string will result in empty string. Therefore, the `-` are simply removed, and for this particular input, the end result is the same.

However, for input such as `--7.3`, the result will be different.

And in Android and GNU Classpath's implementation, [a group that captures nothing is rendered as `null` when referred to in the replacement string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439931/confusion-in-behavior-of-capturing-groups-in-java-regex/27442361#27442361), so your output string in the second case will contain `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The first expression says

*a decimal number, possibly preceded by a `-`*

The second expression says

*A `-` or a decimal number*

When using the expressions as argument to `replaceAll`, you'll (incidentally) get the same result in this case since you set `$1` as the replacement value.

Answer (score 2):

The two expressions have different semantics, even though they happen to produce the same results *for this particular input*.

On some other inputs their result will differ. Consider, for example `1-2`. The first would return `1-2` whereas the second would return `12`.

Answer (score 2):

`?` and `|` are used for different reasons. For example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String yuStr = "--7";
    System.out.println("1 : " +yuStr.replaceAll("-?\\d","")); // replaces the second - and 7
    System.out.println("2 : " +yuStr.replaceAll("-|\\d","")); // replaces all - and all numbers
}
```

prouces the OP :

```
1 : -  // first - is not replaced.
2 :    // empty string
```

It is just a co-incidence that in your case, they produce the same output.
Note : In regex, it is not surprising to have 10 different ways (expressions) to get the same output :)