# How to round floats slightly and cut off trailing zeroes when printing them without using a custom formatter?

Tags: java, floating-point, format

The thing is I need to print numbers like "0.019999979000" as "0.02".

The problem using String.format() is that numbers are either printed like "0.019999979" (%s) or like "0.020000000" (%f).

Is there a way to combine those effects without String manipulations?

UPD: the numbers do not always contain 2 digits after the point - that's just an example to show that the values are very close to the rounded

Comment: Use %.2f to limit it? Not sure if that is what you want to achieve...

Comment: Yep, that's not it. I have numbers of different length

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove trailing zero in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984664/remove-trailing-zero-in-java)

Comment: Do you want to show only one non-zero digit or something else?

if your number is `0.000279` .... you want to show `0.0003` or `0.00028`  ?

Comment: @kevcodez, it's not. The author of the topic you suggested does not require rounding

Comment: @karthik, the numbers are calculated like {1,2,5}*10^(-n)*m and so, they are actually like 0,00015, for example. But because computations are binary, the calculated result is 0,00014999... - very close to the desired. So, it should be rounded really slightly, as format("%f", ...) successfully does. But it keeps the zeroes in trail

Comment: What is the range of `n` and `m`? What I am trying to understand is : "Is your value to be rounded is always less than 1?"

Comment: Does that matter? Well, let's assume, it is.

Comment: @Alex check my answer, let me know If you wanted something else.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a number format based on the number of significant digits. Say, for n = 2, you want to display the number rounded to its first three significant digits, i.e.

```
1234     -> 1200
0.001234 -> 0.0012
1.999    -> 2.0
0.019999979000 -> 0.02
```

In that case, unfortunately, the official Java libraries won't help you (a glaring omission IMO). Under Android at least, you can use

```
new DecimalFormat("@@@")
```

for 3 significant digits; otherwise, you need to look for some available implementations. The only one I know of is the [ICU4J (International Components for Unicode)](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat.html#sigdig), but I have not evaluated it.