# Format float to maximum N decimal places

Tags: java, floating-point, numbers, format

I'd like to format a number to maximum N decimal places. There's [another similar and popular question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places), but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for something like this, let's say I want max. 2 places, so this would be:

```
1.00  -> "1"    (not "1.00")
1.20  -> "1.2"  (not "1.20")
1.23  -> "1.23"
1.234 -> "1.23"
1.235 -> "1.24"
```

The difference to the other question is that I don't want trailing zeros behind the comma if I don't need them.

I'd like to know whether this is doable with **`String.format()`**, not with `Math.round()`, or DecimalFormat. The other question shown above provides a solution with DecimalFormat.

The answer does not need to be variable given N as an argument. I just chose N as an example.

Comment: Please look at the second answer to the question you mentioned.

Comment: Take a look at [using BigDecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13758367/836214) (One of the answers from the question you linked to)

Comment: Solution posted to do just with String.format();

Comment: @Arkadiy - The second answer is DecimalFormat, not String.format(), right?

Comment: You can use DecimalFormat and%s

Comment: Yeah, but my question was whether it's doable with String.format() ...

Comment: @mac did any of the answer solved your question?

Answer (score 8):

You can use **[DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).**

Quoting the documentation:

> You can use the DecimalFormat class to format decimal numbers into locale-specific strings. This class allows you to control the display of leading and trailing zeros, prefixes and suffixes, grouping (thousands) separators, and the decimal separator.
>
> The pound sign (#) denotes a digit and the period is a placeholder for the decimal
> separator.

```
public void test(){
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    System.out.println(df.format(1.00));
    System.out.println(df.format(1.20));
    System.out.println(df.format(1.23));
    System.out.println(df.format(1.234));
    System.out.println(df.format(1.235));
}
```

Output:

```
1
1.2
1.23
1.23
1.24
```

**Update**: since you updated the question and you wanted to use String.format, searching in SO found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0) and leverage a trick plus regex. So, you could use something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(fmt(1.00));
    System.out.println(fmt(1.20));
    System.out.println(fmt(1.23));
    System.out.println(fmt(1.234));
    System.out.println(fmt(1.235));
}

public static String fmt(double d)
{
    if(d == (long) d)
        return String.format("%d",(long)d);
    else
        return String.format("%.2f",d).replaceAll("0*$", "");
}
```

The output is:

```
1
1.2
1.23
1.23
1.24
```

Anyway, I would use **DecimalFormat** instead.

Comment: How would you put the decimal places in terms of `N`?

Comment: @4castle Just make sure there are *N* `#` symbols after the decimal point in the format string.

Comment: Is there a way to encode that with the formatter, or would you have to construct the pattern in a loop with a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: @4castle: you could put multiple ######## as you want. Just put 1 as OP example. If # is found then it is used, is not nothing happens. Different than using 00#.##00, which will populate remaining characters with zeros

Comment: the other question I referenced from the start had a solution with DecimalFormat. I wanted to know what the solution is with String.format() assuming there is one.

Comment: @mac There is a solution with `String.format()`, but it isn't the best solution because it requires string manipulation afterwards.

Comment: @4castle - Yeah, that's not great. So are we saying that there's no solution with String.format(), only with DecimalFormat?

Answer (score 3):

You can also control the formatting of `DecimalFormat` using `setMaximumFractionDigits(...)` like so:

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
for (int i = 2; i < 6; ++i) {
  df.setMaximumFractionDigits(i);
  System.out.println(df.format(d));
}
```

This might be better for your use case than generating a format using `StringBuilder` or similar.

Comment: By default, `DecimalFormat` uses [`RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN) which behaves unexpectedly when rounding a `5`. To fix that, do `df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);`

Answer (score 2):

Use NumberFormat.

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); // or N

System.out.println(format.format(1)); // -> 1
System.out.println(format.format(1.2)); // -> 1.2
System.out.println(format.format(1.23)); // -> 1.23
System.out.println(format.format(1.234)); // -> 1.23
System.out.println(format.format(1.235)); // -> 1.24
```

NumberFormat also works with Locales and you can change the rounding mode.

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

System.out.println(format.format(1)); // -> 1
System.out.println(format.format(1.2)); // -> 1,2
System.out.println(format.format(1.23)); // -> 1,23
System.out.println(format.format(1.234)); // -> 1,24
System.out.println(format.format(1.235)); // -> 1,24
```

Comment: There's a tiny mishap with `formatter` in your second block. It should probably be `format`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you still want to do it with `String.format()`, here is the solution:

Java Code: ParseN.java

```
public class ParseN{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(parseN(1.00));
        System.out.println(parseN(1.20));
        System.out.println(parseN(1.23));
        System.out.println(parseN(1.234));
        System.out.println(parseN(1.235));
     }

     static String parseN(Double d)
     {
       String s = String.format("%.2f", d);
       s = s.indexOf(".") < 0 ? s : s.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
       return s;
     }
}
```

output:

```
1
1.2
1.23
1.23
1.24
```

Hope it fully answers your question. Also, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984664/remove-trailing-zero-in-java).

Comment: You can consolidate the 2 regex to be `\\.?0*$`. Also, there will always be a decimal point in the resulting string, so the `indexOf` ternary isn't needed. If you put `N` into the format string, this may be the most complete answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the most concise way using `String.format()` would be through the `fmt` expression shown in the following test program:

```java
static String fmtN(double d) {
    String fmt = String.format("%.2f", d).replaceFirst("\\.?(\\.[1-9])?0+$", "$1");
    System.out.println(fmt);
    return fmt;
}

@Test
public void test() {
    assertThat(fmtN(1), is("1"));
    assertThat(fmtN(1.05), is("1.05"));
    assertThat(fmtN(1.2), is("1.2"));
    assertThat(fmtN(1.23), is("1.23"));
    assertThat(fmtN(1.234), is("1.23"));
    assertThat(fmtN(1.235), is("1.24"));
}
```

##### All the gory details

Formatters available to `String.format()` don't readily allow specifying "maximum N" decimal places (only "exactly 2" for example, as in `.2`) so we have to use a [Regex](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to strip trailing zeroes.  This is a bit harder than it looks for the first case (where there are no decimal places), in order to also suppress the trailing `.`.

Here are a few key points that make this work:

- `?` makes the [preceding group or pattern optional](https://www.pythonpool.com/regex-optional-group/)
- `(...)` delimits a capturing group, which can be re-introduced in the replacement string using its positional number; so here `$1` reproduces the capturing group `(\.[1-9])`
- `+` is for one or more occurrences of the preceding pattern
- `\.` escapes the `.` (decimal point) character, so it's used as a literal rather than its regex meaning of "any character" (backslashes have to themselves to be escaped in Java Strings, so every regex backslash is written `\\`).

Pfeeew... So the capturing group `(\.[1-9])`, meaning a `.` followed by any non-zero digit is marked optional using the `?` suffix; so the entire regex doesn't fail to match in case there are no non-zero decimal places, as in the test string `1.00`.  If that group is present, it gets replicated using `$1` as we saw above.  If it isn't present (as in `1.00`), we want the `.` (decimal point) stripped so it gets captured by `\.?`.  Trailing zeroes are captured by `0+$` (`$` stands for end of candidate string) and discarded.

Finally I used `replaceFirst()` as opposed to `replaceAll()` as a minor optimization; once the regex has done it's job, we can stop looking for more matches.