# How to convert double to String and remove all trailing zero behind the point value?

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, double, number-formatting

I have looking for the solution around and doing a little workaround here, but can not wrap up all to meet my expectations. For example, I have double values as below

```
double x = 101.00000
double y = 102.02000
double z = 103.20000
double k = 104.30020
```

I want all the value to become String with the smallest number of decimal they have to show. Expected result

```
String l = "101"
String m = "102.02"
String n = "103.2"
String o = "104.3002"
// and the l = formatted x, m = formatted y, n = formatted z, o = formatted k
```

Can this be achieved in any way?

(Note: someone have suggest my question may duplicate with remove trailing zero in java, but I suggest it's different because in my question the base value is double not String)

Comment: I think no bro @Torben, my question base value is double so I need to convert the value to String and do the formatting at the same time

Comment: You do not understand your problem correctly, Fran. Your problem is not about double values. It's about "string representation of double values." Until you understand the difference between those, you probably should try to maintain a repectful attitude to those helping you and refrain from incorrectly referring to them as "bros".

Comment: I appologize for using terms 'bro'. And thanks a lot @Torben for the critics. I accept your criticism and suggestions. But still I am on my opinion that the root problem of my question and the question you suggest a little bit different. The question you directing me to is about how to reformat a String(which may / always contains a numeric value in decimals or any other) to remove the trailing zero value in it. Thanks a lot. anyone seen this and think I am wrong please notify me too, and I might take it down then. I doesn't want to spread any miss understanding and bad intention. Sorry

Comment: Please check your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984664/remove-trailing-zero-in-java/74925939#74925939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
public static String format(double val) {
     if(val == (long)val) 
          return String.format("%d", (long) val);
     else
          return String.format("%s", val);
}
```

Input:

```
1. 101.00000
2. 102.02000
```

Output:

```
1. 101
2. 102.02
```

Comment: I still have some question. Do in java casting ```(long) val``` will never throw any error?? I see in the implementation it's simply just need to cast the value and compare it to the original value

Comment: This will fail when val exceeds Long.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score -1):

**CONVERT DOUBLE TO STRING**

In Java, if you want to convert a value type to another, you should see this 'another type' class and try to find a converting method.

I this case you want to convert a Double type to String. String class has a method called `String.valueOf(double d)` that changes the number value to String. It also can convert other number types to String thanks to the overload properties.

---

**REMOVING UNNECESSARY ZERO**

Once you have the String values, use this code with each one to remove the unnecessary zeros.

```
s = s.indexOf(".") < 0 ? s : s.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
```

---

In your case:

```
Double x = 101.00000;
Double y = 102.02000;
Double z = 103.20000;
Double k = 104.30020;

String l = String.valueOf(x);
String m = String.valueOf(y);
String n = String.valueOf(z);
String o = String.valueOf(k);

l = l.indexOf(".") < 0 ? l : l.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
m = m.indexOf(".") < 0 ? m : m.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
n = n.indexOf(".") < 0 ? n : n.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
o = o.indexOf(".") < 0 ? o : o.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
```

Output:

- 101
- 102.02
- 103.2
- 104.3002