# Serialise BigDecimal value with customised scale per class field

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, annotations, bigdecimal

I have a `JSON` seriliazer which serializes a `BigDecimal` in the way presented in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540939/20015890):

```
public class MoneySerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal bigDecimal, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(bigDecimal.toPlainString());
    }
}
```

It is used in my `POJO`:

```
public class MoneyBean {
    //...

    @JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)
    private BigDecimal amount1;

    @JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)
    private BigDecimal amount2;
  
    // getters/setters
}
```

Requirements:

1. I have to remove all trailing zeros but keep two from amount1 eg: if result is 100.0000 - intended result is 100.00
2. For amount2 I have to remove all trailing zeros eg: if result is 100.0000 - intended result is 100

Is there any way the `MoneySerializer` can be adjusted to pass another argument as `minimumScale` so that it can remove automatically? Obviously this logic can be moved to service or we can create different serializer for each case but here I am looking for a single annotation which solves the problem something like :

```java
@MyJsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class, minimumScale = 2)
private BigDecimal amount1;  //100.00000 -> 100.00

@MyJsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class, minimumScale = 0)
private BigDecimal amount2; //100.00000 -> 100

@MyJsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class, minimumScale = 4)
private BigDecimal amount3;   //100.00000 -> 100.0000
```

Tried with different serializer or moving trailing zeros removal logic to service class and that is working but looking for a configurable annotation based solution.

Answer (score 1):

When we want to customise serialiser per field we need to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.ContextualSerializer` to create customised version. It allows us to read annotation for a given field and we do that only once so during the serialisation we do not need to execute `Reflection API`. Also, we can reuse `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat` annotation to provide pattern for `BigDecimal`. Using `JsonFormat` we can also handle shape in case we want to print it as a number for some properties. Below you can find complete example:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat.Shape;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.ContextualSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;
import lombok.Data;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Objects;

public class BigDecimalApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        var mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .build();

        var entity = new Entity();
        entity.setAmount1(new BigDecimal("100.4567"));
        entity.setAmount2(new BigDecimal("100.4567"));
        entity.setAmount3(new BigDecimal("100.4567"));
        entity.setAmountAsNumber1(new BigDecimal("100.4567"));
        entity.setAmountAsNumber2(new BigDecimal("100.4567"));
        entity.setAmountAsNumber3(new BigDecimal("100.4567"));

        mapper.writeValue(System.out, entity);
    }
}

@Data
class Entity {

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "#")
    @JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)
    private BigDecimal amount1;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "#.00")
    @JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)
    private BigDecimal amount2;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "#.0000")
    @JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)
    private BigDecimal amount3;

    @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.NUMBER_INT)
    @JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)
    private BigDecimal amountAsNumber1;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "#.00", shape = Shape.NUMBER)
    @JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)
    private BigDecimal amountAsNumber2;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "#.0000", shape = Shape.NUMBER)
    @JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)
    private BigDecimal amountAsNumber3;
}

class MoneySerializer extends StdSerializer<BigDecimal> implements ContextualSerializer {

    private static final MoneySerializer INSTANCE = new MoneySerializer();

    private final NumberFormat formatter;
    private final Shape shape;

    public MoneySerializer() {
        this(DecimalFormat.getInstance(), Shape.STRING);
    }

    protected MoneySerializer(NumberFormat formatter, Shape shape) {
        super(BigDecimal.class);
        this.formatter = Objects.requireNonNull(formatter);
        this.shape = Objects.requireNonNull(shape);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        if (Objects.isNull(value)) {
            jsonGenerator.writeNull();
        } else {
            switch (shape) {
                case NUMBER, NUMBER_FLOAT, NATURAL -> jsonGenerator.writeNumber(value.setScale(formatter.getMaximumFractionDigits(), RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
                case NUMBER_INT -> jsonGenerator.writeNumber(value.intValue());
                default -> jsonGenerator.writeString(formatter.format(value));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) {
        JsonFormat jsonFormat = property.getAnnotation(JsonFormat.class);
        if (Objects.isNull(jsonFormat)) {
            return INSTANCE;
        }

        return new MoneySerializer(new DecimalFormat(jsonFormat.pattern()), jsonFormat.shape());
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```json
{
  "amount1" : "100",
  "amount2" : "100.46",
  "amount3" : "100.4567",
  "amountAsNumber1" : 100,
  "amountAsNumber2" : 100.46,
  "amountAsNumber3" : 100.4567
}
```

See also:

- [Java to Jackson JSON serialization: Money fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319445/java-to-jackson-json-serialization-money-fields)
- [How to print formatted BigDecimal values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values)

Comment: Thanks, @Michal. The solution works for all required test cases, but is there a way we can tweak this to serialize a BigDecimal number just as a String and remove trailing zeros? 
eg: number = 1000.0001123000 =>  "1000.0001123", and  1000.000 ==> "1000"

Comment: @luke, you can use pattern like this: `0.####` if you want to remove zeros. Take a look at [Remove trailing zero in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14988679/51591)

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and thought about the code for you before I went to bed. Try what I wrote ：)

add this annotation class

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAccuracy {
    int value() default 0;
}
```

and

```
public class Entity {

@MyAccuracy(2)
@JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)
public BigDecimal amount1;


@MyAccuracy(0)
@JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)
public BigDecimal amount2;

@MyAccuracy(4)
@JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)
public BigDecimal amount3;


}
```

and

```
public class MoneySerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {



@Override
public void serialize(BigDecimal bigDecimal, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
    String fieldName = jsonGenerator.getOutputContext().getCurrentName();
    Class css = jsonGenerator.getOutputContext().getCurrentValue().getClass();
    boolean edit = false;
    try{
        MyAccuracy myAccuracy = css.getField(fieldName).getAnnotation(MyAccuracy.class);
        jsonGenerator.writeString(bigDecimal.setScale(myAccuracy.value(),BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString());
        edit = true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(!edit) {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(bigDecimal.toPlainString());
    }
}

}
```

finally

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Entity entity = new Entity();
    entity.amount1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(2.2222);
    entity.amount2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(3.3333);
    entity.amount3 = BigDecimal.valueOf(4.4444);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity);
    System.out.println(jsonString);
}
```

final result

```
{"amount1":"2.22","amount2":"3","amount3":"4.4444"}
```

Good luck~

Comment: Thanks, @Lian. The solution works. If accessing private fields we should replace ```css.getField(fieldName)```  to ```css.getDeclaredField(fieldName)```

Comment: Oh, yee，I accidentally left that out XD

Comment: Hey, take a look on my answer with `ContextualSerializer` where we can check annotation only once. You can also implement this interface in your example. It will simplify and improve performance of `serialize` method.

Comment: Thanks, @Michal Ziober - This really helps, its solves one of the problems which I didn't ask about (printing as int/number format).